# Which classification are of cookie are the jquery cookies __utma __utmb __utmz

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cookies

I am using the jquery mobile framework and performing a cookie audit. Which of the following classifications do the jquery cookies __utma, __utmb and __utmz fall into?

[image: jQuery Cookies]

1. ‘Strictly Necessary’ cookies let you move around the website and use
   essential features such as our searches and our logged-in areas.
2. ‘Performance’ cookies collect information about how you use our
       website e.g. which pages you visit.
3. ‘Functionality’ cookies are used to provide our core services or to
       save settings to improve your visit.
4. ‘Targeting’ cookies are deployed by third parties, such as Facebook,
   Twitter and our advertising partners. They may subsequently use
   information about your visit to target you with advertising that you
   may be interested in, on this and other websites.

Comment: Hi, where does that classification come? Is this a standard classification? I'm very interested in that byt I haven't found any references

Answer (score 3):

Those three cookies are created by Google Analytics, not jQuery Mobile. They are "performance" cookies, according to your classification, used to track a user's activity on the site. Read more about Google Analytics [here](http://www.google.com/analytics/) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Analytics).

Comment: I have added a screenshot from my Firefox console. As far a I am aware these cookies are related to jQuery.

Comment: [Here is the related script that sets those cookies](http://www.google-analytics.com/urchin.js)

Comment: UTM stands for `Urchin Traffic Monitor` And here is a [Google document](http://support.google.com/urchin/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=28710) about UTM.

Comment: Abraham is correct - __utm cookies are used by Google Analytics. It's strange that those are being set on domain .jquery.com - if they were tracking your site they should be set on .yourdomain.com. Either they are misconfigured or maybe operating through a jquery plugin. Not really sure without seeing more detail of the site.

Comment: If you use jquery.com as a CDN for loading your scripts, you end up eating jquery.com's Analytic service cookies.

Comment: @Abraham this is weird. I too have on a site i'm developing, this utmz jquery cookie and btw i have no GA code in it.

Comment: Commenting from the future… this still happens. So it looks like if your Europe-based site loads jQuery from their CDN, to remain within the law you must either implement a cookie permissions dialog, or host jQuery on your own server instead.